# How to trim the longest match from beginning of a string (using python)

Tags: python, string

In recent bash versions, I can do this:

```
$ string="Universe.World.Country.State.City.Street"
$ echo $string
Universe.World.Country.State.City.Street
$ newString="${string##*.}"
$ echo $newString
Street
```

Using Python, what is a succinct way to doing the same?
I am interested in the last substring after the last period.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

How about

```
x[x.rfind('.') + 1 : ]
```

To me, that expresses what you're interested in (find the last dot, then take everything after it) more simply than a pattern or the concept of a "longest match".

Comment: @Downvoter: please leave a comment to explain... I'm a newbie at Python, so I'd really appreciate guidance if I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I'd imagine it looks too much like C and not python.

Comment: This is pretty clever, but the `x.rpartition()` solution is the exact solution to the problem.  In Python it is generally considered best to simply get what you want, rather than getting an index to what you want and then extract what you want; thus we prefer solutions that use `for x in some_list` rather than `for i in xrange(len(some_list))` and then using `some_list[i]` to access each item.  But a downvote is unduly harsh!

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> 'Universe.World.Country.State.City.Street'.rpartition('.')[2]
'Street'
```

Comment: This is the fastest way anyone has posted so far

Comment: I like rpartition. It uses a python string lib. Easy to read. And seems analogous to the spirit of the bash operation. Everyone here is awesome! I learned so much more than just how to trim that string, too. Thanks! (The rsplit is appealing too)

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> "Universe.World.Country.State.City.Street".rsplit('.',1)[1]
'Street'
```

Edit: rpartition as suggested by SilentGhost seems to be the most efficient

```
# rpartition
$ python -m timeit -r100 -n100 -s 'x="Universe.World.Country.State.City.Street"' 'x.rpartition(".")[-1]'
100 loops, best of 100: 0.749 usec per loop

# rfind
$ python -m timeit -r100 -n100 -s 'x="Universe.World.Country.State.City.Street"' 'x[x.rfind(".")+1:]'
100 loops, best of 100: 0.808 usec per loop

# rsplit
$ python -m timeit -r100 -n100 -s 'x="Universe.World.Country.State.City.Street"' 'x.rsplit(".",1)[1]'
100 loops, best of 100: 0.858 usec per loop

# split
$ python -m timeit -r100 -n100 -s 'x="Universe.World.Country.State.City.Street"' 'x.split(".")[-1]'
100 loops, best of 100: 1.26 usec per loop

# regex
$ python -m timeit -r100 -n100 -s 'import re;rex=re.compile(r"\.([^.]*)$");x="Universe.World.Country.State.City.Street"' 'rex.search(x).groups()[0]'
100 loops, best of 100: 3.16 usec per loop
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe:

```
re.search(r"\.([^.]*)$", s).groups()[0]
```

EDIT: First version was bad :)

Answer (score 0):

If you know its always going to be the last element and a full stop you can't beat

```
"Universe.World.Country.State.City.Street".split(".")[-1]
```

Comment: Won't that go to all the trouble of finding *all* the dots, and create a whole list/array of strings, even though you know perfectly well you only want the last one?

Comment: Given that his string is only 6 elements long, I think that it would be eager optimisation to try anything that is harder to read.

Comment: string.rsplit('.', 1) with maxsplit=1 also returns only the rightmost '.'

Answer (score 0):

`string.rsplit('.', 1)[-1]` with maxsplit=1 returns only the rightmost '.', so it also only matches once.

Looks like a tossup with `string.rpartition('.')[-1]`

PS: gnibbler actually timed rsplit and it was slightly slower than rpartition, rfind.